# Importjson exclude parameters spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

How I can use importjson show only result parameter?

Example:

```
=IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin", "/name")
```

---

```
"Name"  
"Bitcoin"
```

I need show only this:

```
"Bitcoin"
```

my idea is to use my blog to display the latest quotations https://1bitcoinhoje.com

Answer (score 0):

Just parse your `rawHeaders` :

```
=ImportJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin","/name","noHeaders")
```

ImportJSON has parse-Options for `rawHeaders` :

- `noHeaders` : don’t include headers, only the data
- `debugLocation` : prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in.
- `noInherit` : don’t inherit values from parent elements
- `noTruncate`: don’t truncate values
- `rawHeaders`: don’t prettify headers