# Using cell adjacent to ImportJSON throws error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I am importing an individual parameter using the importJSON function in Google Sheets.

See post: [Importjson exclude parameters spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645999/importjson-exclude-parameters-spreadsheet/64674947#64674947)

When I use

```
=importJSON("url", "/name","noHeaders")
```

this works perfectly to import the exact cell I need but I cannot use the cell to the right of the import.

E.G:

Cell A1 `=importJSON("url", "/name","noHeaders")`, If I type any text into Cell B1 I receive

> "Error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B1"

and Cell A1 displays `#REF!`. Then once I delete text in B1 the importJSON value reappears back into A1 and the error clears. Is there a way to fix this so I can have data next to the importJSON cell?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want 1 value from the import, `INDEX` into it:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTJSON("url", "/name","noHeaders"), 1, 1)
```

You may also use `ARRAYCONSTRAIN()` to constrain the array.

#### Syntax:

```
=INDEX(array, [row], [column])
```

Comment: That worked well. I have another question but may have to ask this in a seperate forum. When using the importJSON function in a cell am I able to use this cell in other cell formulas? E.G: Cell A1 contains =importJSON("url", "/name", "noHeaders"),1,1) which displays a value of 100. Can I then use this in a formula in Cell B1? E.G: Cell B1 formula =IF(AND(A1>50), "Y", "N")). Currently the formula doesn't work

Comment: @Ronhamilton Ask new questions in a new post. But As a preliminary answer, it should work- check whether they're actually numbers and not strings. For this  question, Consider accepting the answer, if it helped you.